# Divide Numbers by 0

Tags: code-golf, math, number

We've all been told at some point in our lives that dividing by 0 is impossible. And for the most part, that statement is true. But what if there *was* a way to perform the forbidden operation? Welcome to  my newest creation: `b`-numbers.

`b`-numbers are a little bit like imaginary numbers: the main pronumeral involved represents an expression that isn't mathematically impossible (`i` represents \$\sqrt{-1}\$).
In this case \$b\$ will be said to represent the expression \$\frac{1}{0}\$. From here, it is easy to determine what \$\frac{x}{0}\$ would equal:

$$
\frac{x}{0} = \frac{x}{1} \cdot \frac{1}{0} = xb
$$

### The Task

Given an expression  involving a division by 0, output the simplified value in terms of \$b\$. Note that input will be in the form of `n/0` where n is any rational number or any `b`-number in decimal form. Leading 0s and trailing 0s wont be included.

### Example Input

```
4/0
1/0
0/0
80/0
-8/0
1.5/0
2.03/0
-1/0
-3.14/0
b/0
3b/0
-b/0
121/0
```

### Example Output

```
4b
b
0
80b
-8b
1.5b
2.03b
-b
-3.14b
b
3b
-b
121b
```

## Score

This is code golf, so fewest bytes wins. Standard loopholes are forbidden.

### Leaderboards

Here is a Stack Snippet to generate both a regular leaderboard and an overview of winners by language.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
# Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
# Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

If there you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in the header:

```
# Perl, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the leaderboard snippet:

```
# [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 121 bytes
```

```js
var QUESTION_ID=191101;
var OVERRIDE_USER=8478;
var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;function answersUrl(d){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+d+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(d,e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+e.join(";")+"/comments?page="+d+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(d){answers.push.apply(answers,d.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],d.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var f=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(f),answers_hash[f]=e}),d.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(d){d.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),d.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=function(){var d=String.raw`h\d`,e=String.raw`\-?\d+\.?\d*`,f=String.raw`[^\n<>]*`,g=String.raw`<s>${f}</s>|<strike>${f}</strike>|<del>${f}</del>`,h=String.raw`[^\n\d<>]*`,j=String.raw`<[^\n<>]+>`;return new RegExp(String.raw`<${d}>`+String.raw`\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?`+String.raw`(${e})`+String.raw`(?=`+String.raw`${h}`+String.raw`(?:(?:${g}|${j})${h})*`+String.raw`</${d}>`+String.raw`)`)}(),OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;function getAuthorName(d){return d.owner.display_name}function process(){var d=[];answers.forEach(function(n){var o=n.body;n.comments.forEach(function(q){OVERRIDE_REG.test(q.body)&&(o="<h1>"+q.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var p=o.match(SCORE_REG);p&&d.push({user:getAuthorName(n),size:+p[2],language:p[1],link:n.share_link})}),d.sort(function(n,o){var p=n.size,q=o.size;return p-q});var e={},f=1,g=null,h=1;d.forEach(function(n){n.size!=g&&(h=f),g=n.size,++f;var o=jQuery("#answer-template").html();o=o.replace("{{PLACE}}",h+".").replace("{{NAME}}",n.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",n.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",n.size).replace("{{LINK}}",n.link),o=jQuery(o),jQuery("#answers").append(o);var p=n.language;p=jQuery("<i>"+n.language+"</i>").text().toLowerCase(),e[p]=e[p]||{lang:n.language,user:n.user,size:n.size,link:n.link,uniq:p}});var j=[];for(var k in e)e.hasOwnProperty(k)&&j.push(e[k]);j.sort(function(n,o){return n.uniq>o.uniq?1:n.uniq<o.uniq?-1:0});for(var l=0;l<j.length;++l){var m=jQuery("#language-template").html(),k=j[l];m=m.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",k.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",k.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",k.size).replace("{{LINK}}",k.link),m=jQuery(m),jQuery("#languages").append(m)}}
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list{padding:10px;float:left}#language-list{padding:10px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/codegolf/primary.css?v=f52df912b654"> <div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">{{SIZE}}</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">{{SIZE}}</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: 1/0 (b) ÷ 0/1 (0) = 0/0

Comment: 1/0 (b) ÷ 0/1 = 1/0 × 1 = 1/0 (b)

Comment: Suggested test case `-3.14b/0` - I had some short code that'd work for all other test cases :(

Comment: I suspect that I'm doing something wrong, but if `b/0 = b` then if I divide both parts by `b` then `1/0 = 1`. Do I need `c`-numbers to divide like this?

Comment: @someone \$\frac x b=\frac x{\frac10}=\frac{\frac x1}{\frac10}=\frac{x\cdot0}{1\cdot1}=\frac01=0\$. That is, dividing by \$b\$ results in \$0\$, so dividing both parts by \$b\$ leads to \$0=0\$, not \$b=1\$.

Comment: @Erik that way, `b/b = 0` when it's normally (and I'm pretty sure it's easily proven from all the various axioms) expected to be 1 (otherwise, b's multiplicative inverse seems to be not its multiplicative inverse). I'm pretty sure you just can't loophole against division by zero by adding `b=1/0` or anything similar.

Comment: @someone TBF, the normal axioms don't exactly hold when you define division by zero anyway, so you still can't just "divide \$b\$ from both sides", or at least expect that \$\frac b b=1\$... :P My equation uses undefined stuff in it, based on how I would define them. ;)

Comment: There's a reason division by zero is undefined... \$b=1\cdot b=\frac11\cdot b=\frac33\cdot b=\frac{3\cdot1}{3\cdot0}=\frac30=3\cdot\frac10=3b\$. So you should be able to simplify all the examples (excepting the third of 0) to just \$b\$

Comment: Shouldn't the 3rd example have output `0b` rather than `0`? If the two expressions were equivalent then the question would have no premise

Comment: @trichoplax Indeed, if $0b=0$ (which example 3 suggests), then $b/0 = (0b)/0 = b \cdot (0/0) = b\cdot 0 = 0$. Then, to maintain consistency with the example $b/0 = b$, we must have $b=0$, and so $x\cdot b = x\cdot 0 = 0 = 0b$ for any $x$ in our original ring as well (assuming standard ring axioms), which renders the challenge moot. Btw, it is possible to make division by zero well defined (e.g. [wheel theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_theory)), but you have to redefine 'division' to make it not _quite_ the same as a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: Maybe it is also possible to make it well defined by restricting some distributive properties of division and multiplication? E.g, the false derivation $i = \sqrt{-1} = \sqrt{1/(-1)} = \sqrt{1}/\sqrt{-1} = 1/i = -i$ is 'possible' since distributing square roots over division no longer works if we 'allow' square roots of negative numbers. So maybe removing the rule $(ab)/c = a(b/c)$ and replacing it by something more restrictive can make this system non-trivial (i.e. ensure that not everything is equal)

Comment: Suggested test case: [`3.1b/0`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/191101/divide-numbers-by-0#comment457126_191108)

Comment: The "standard" way to make division by zero sensible is the _projectively extended real line_, which adds a single value ∞ (no separate +∞ and -∞!). Then x÷0 for any x≠0 is ∞, and things work out fine—as long as you're okay with weirdnesses like ∞÷2=∞. You'll find if you play around a bit that, if you want addition and multiplication to keep as many of their standard properties as possible, then your *b* must have properties more consistent with infinity than with anything else (b+1=b, b×2=b, b÷2=b, and so on).

Comment: Since \$x/0=xb\$ why not \$b/0=bb=b^2\$?

Comment: \$\frac{1}{0}=b\implies 0\times b = 1\$ we have \$ 1=0\times b=0\times \frac{1}{0}=0\times\frac{1\times 1}{0\times 0}=0\times\frac{1}{0}\times\frac{1}{0}=0\times b\times b=1\times b=b \$, then \$ 1=b\times 0=1\times 0=0\$

Comment: Hm... Your type of imaginary number has interesting property: $$\frac{b^{b}}{b}=1$$

Comment: Can we use a different symbol for division instead of `/`?

Comment: Is `1b` and `0b` simplified enough for testcases (2) & (3)? Or should it be exactly like the example output?

Answer (score 28):

## Malbolge Unshackled (20-trit rotation variant), 3,62e6 bytes

Size of this answer exceeds maximum postable program size (eh), so the code is [located in my GitHub repository](https://github.com/KrzysztofSzewczyk/codegolf-submissions/raw/master/191101.mu) (note: Don't copy the code using CTRL+A and CTRL+C, just rightclick and click "Save destination element as...").

### How to run this?

This might be a tricky part, because naive Haskell interpreter will take ages upon ages to run this. TIO has decent Malbogle Unshackled interpreter, but sadly I won't be able to use it (limitations).

The best one I could find is the fixed 20-trit rotation width variant, that performs very well, **calculating (pretty much) instantly**.

To make the interpreter a bit faster, I've removed all the checks from Matthias Lutter's Malbolge Unshackled interpreter.

```c
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char* translation = "5z]&gqtyfr$(we4{WP)H-Zn,[%\\3dL+Q;>U!pJS72Fh"
        "OA1CB6v^=I_0/8|jsb9m<.TVac`uY*MK'X~xDl}REokN:#?G\"i@";

typedef struct Word {
    unsigned int area;
    unsigned int high;
    unsigned int low;
} Word;

void word2string(Word w, char* s, int min_length) {
    if (!s) return;
    if (min_length < 1) min_length = 1;
    if (min_length > 20) min_length = 20;
    s[0] = (w.area%3) + '0';
    s[1] = 't';
    char tmp[20];
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
        tmp[19-i] = (w.low % 3) + '0';
        w.low /= 3;
    }
    for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
        tmp[9-i] = (w.high % 3) + '0';
        w.high /= 3;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (tmp[i] == s[0] && i < 20 - min_length) i++;
    int j = 2;
    while (i < 20) {
        s[j] = tmp[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    s[j] = 0;
}

unsigned int crazy_low(unsigned int a, unsigned int d){
    unsigned int crz[] = {1,0,0,1,0,2,2,2,1};
    int position = 0;
    unsigned int output = 0;
    while (position < 10){
        unsigned int i = a%3;
        unsigned int j = d%3;
        unsigned int out = crz[i+3*j];
        unsigned int multiple = 1;
        int k;
        for (k=0;k<position;k++)
            multiple *= 3;
        output += multiple*out;
        a /= 3;
        d /= 3;
        position++;
    }
    return output;
}

Word zero() {
    Word result = {0, 0, 0};
    return result;
}

Word increment(Word d) {
    d.low++;
    if (d.low >= 59049) {
        d.low = 0;
        d.high++;
        if (d.high >= 59049) {
            fprintf(stderr,"error: overflow\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    return d;
}

Word decrement(Word d) {
    if (d.low == 0) {
        d.low = 59048;
        d.high--;
    }else{
        d.low--;
    }
    return d;
}

Word crazy(Word a, Word d){
    Word output;
    unsigned int crz[] = {1,0,0,1,0,2,2,2,1};
    output.area = crz[a.area+3*d.area];
    output.high = crazy_low(a.high, d.high);
    output.low = crazy_low(a.low, d.low);
    return output;
}

Word rotate_r(Word d){
    unsigned int carry_h = d.high%3;
    unsigned int carry_l = d.low%3;
    d.high = 19683 * carry_l + d.high / 3;
    d.low = 19683 * carry_h + d.low / 3;
    return d;
}

// last_initialized: if set, use to fill newly generated memory with preinitial values...
Word* ptr_to(Word** mem[], Word d, unsigned int last_initialized) {
    if ((mem[d.area])[d.high]) {
        return &(((mem[d.area])[d.high])[d.low]);
    }
    (mem[d.area])[d.high] = (Word*)malloc(59049 * sizeof(Word));
    if (!(mem[d.area])[d.high]) {
        fprintf(stderr,"error: out of memory.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (last_initialized) {
        Word repitition[6];
        repitition[(last_initialized-1) % 6] =
                ((mem[0])[(last_initialized-1) / 59049])
                    [(last_initialized-1) % 59049];
        repitition[(last_initialized) % 6] =
                ((mem[0])[last_initialized / 59049])
                    [last_initialized % 59049];
        unsigned int i;
        for (i=0;i<6;i++) {
            repitition[(last_initialized+1+i) % 6] =
                    crazy(repitition[(last_initialized+i) % 6],
                        repitition[(last_initialized-1+i) % 6]);
        }
        unsigned int offset = (59049*d.high) % 6;
        i = 0;
        while (1){
            ((mem[d.area])[d.high])[i] = repitition[(i+offset)%6];
            if (i == 59048) {
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    return &(((mem[d.area])[d.high])[d.low]);
}

unsigned int get_instruction(Word** mem[], Word c,
        unsigned int last_initialized,
        int ignore_invalid) {
    Word* instr = ptr_to(mem, c, last_initialized);
    unsigned int instruction = instr->low;
    instruction = (instruction+c.low + 59049 * c.high
            + (c.area==1?52:(c.area==2?10:0)))%94;
    return instruction;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Word** memory[3];
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
        memory[i] = (Word**)malloc(59049 * sizeof(Word*));
        if (!memory) {
            fprintf(stderr,"not enough memory.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        for (j=0; j<59049; j++) {
            (memory[i])[j] = 0;
        }
    }
    Word a, c, d;
    unsigned int result;
    FILE* file;
    if (argc < 2) {
        // read program code from STDIN
        file = stdin;
    }else{
        file = fopen(argv[1],"rb");
    }
    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "File not found: %s\n",argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    a = zero();
    c = zero();
    d = zero();
    result = 0;
    while (!feof(file)){
        unsigned int instr;
        Word* cell = ptr_to(memory, d, 0);
        (*cell) = zero();
        result = fread(&cell->low,1,1,file);
        if (result > 1)
            return 1;
        if (result == 0 || cell->low == 0x1a || cell->low == 0x04)
            break;
        instr = (cell->low + d.low + 59049*d.high)%94;
        if (cell->low == ' ' || cell->low == '\t' || cell->low == '\r'
                || cell->low == '\n');
        else if (cell->low >= 33 && cell->low < 127 &&
                (instr == 4 || instr == 5 || instr == 23 || instr == 39
                    || instr == 40 || instr == 62 || instr == 68
                    || instr == 81)) {
            d = increment(d);
        }
    }
    if (file != stdin) {
        fclose(file);
    }
    unsigned int last_initialized = 0;
    while (1){
        *ptr_to(memory, d, 0) = crazy(*ptr_to(memory, decrement(d), 0),
                *ptr_to(memory, decrement(decrement(d)), 0));
        last_initialized = d.low + 59049*d.high;
        if (d.low == 59048) {
            break;
        }
        d = increment(d);
    }
    d = zero();

    unsigned int step = 0;
    while (1) {
        unsigned int instruction = get_instruction(memory, c,
                last_initialized, 0);
        step++;
        switch (instruction){
            case 4:
                c = *ptr_to(memory,d,last_initialized);
                break;
            case 5:
                if (!a.area) {
                    printf("%c",(char)(a.low + 59049*a.high));
                }else if (a.area == 2 && a.low == 59047
                        && a.high == 59048) {
                    printf("\n");
                }
                break;
            case 23:
                a = zero();
                a.low = getchar();
                if (a.low == EOF) {
                    a.low = 59048;
                    a.high = 59048;
                    a.area = 2;
                }else if (a.low == '\n'){
                    a.low = 59047;
                    a.high = 59048;
                    a.area = 2;
                }
                break;
            case 39:
                a = (*ptr_to(memory,d,last_initialized)
                        = rotate_r(*ptr_to(memory,d,last_initialized)));
                break;
            case 40:
                d = *ptr_to(memory,d,last_initialized);
                break;
            case 62:
                a = (*ptr_to(memory,d,last_initialized)
                        = crazy(a, *ptr_to(memory,d,last_initialized)));
                break;
            case 81:
                return 0;
            case 68:
            default:
                break;
        }

        Word* mem_c = ptr_to(memory, c, last_initialized);
        mem_c->low = translation[mem_c->low - 33];

        c = increment(c);
        d = increment(d);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### It's working!

[image: It's working!]

Comment: I hope you didn't type all that.

Comment: When I opened your program, Chrome attempted to translate it from Polish

Comment: How to generate this program?

Answer (score 9):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>65</s> <s>64</s> <s>61</s> 58 bytes

-1 byte by using a `b` instead of `''` (empty string). Since "b"s are trimmed, it will be same as an empty string in this specific case.

-3 bytes by using `substr` instead of `explode` to get first part of input.

-3 bytes by using better methods to detect `1` and `-1`.

```php
<?=($n=substr($argn,0,-2))?trim($n+1?$n-1?$n:b:'-',b).b:0;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FckxDoAgDADAz5AgkSKoE0rY/IcsymAhgN@36nLL5TMTrd51DF29Q22lY3s5UGoJoxC@lXh91xvPEH5ssBy4DEIFqxcimJSZB/2k3GLCSrC9)

Tests: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9BDoIwEEX3PcWEkACRYgFNDJWw8wBu1QUlKCZaGlpWxqtbazFpu2jezP9/2hGD0PtGDAKhUPVSSajhhMCcaLMmUbpg7pA43HmMd54727qiyEjp2bxJuMxy7w3msPQYe5wXS/xCEbqOU992A8T/b7cSLCXwsuawnW7cLGOb1Lb6bhghOPZyfigw@UWrIKD6J8Uhr@XMpJpiG05JioskadR0fxptlTchx7@rYlWEo5QlGasI1W70mQcUvbVZ6jMKdR@51PjwBQ)

If first part of input before "/" (we call it `$n`) is 0, prints 0.

Else prints `$n` itself with any "b" at the end trimmed from it and special cases of -1 and 1 handled, so the "1" digit is not printed. And at the end appends a single "b". The trimming part is to make sure we don't get a double "b" at the end like "3bb".

Comment: very nicely done!

Comment: Replacing `$n==-1` with `$n>0` (-2 bytes) seems to work. You could try that.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, that is not working, if you meant `$n<0`, that won't work too, since we have inputs like `-8/0`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, but you gave me an idea, replaced `$n==-1?'-':$n` with `$n+1?$n:'-'` to save 2 bytes!

Comment: :/ When I tested, it seemed to work. but well, good thing that you found another way.

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 32 bytes

```perl6
{~m/^0/||S/[(\-|^)1|b]?\/0/$0b/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv7ouVz/OQL@mJlg/WiNGtyZO07AmKdY@Rt9AX8UgSb/2f05mXmqxnZ2eWhqQKE6s/G@ib8BlCMQGQGwBInQtQCJ6pkDSSM/AGCQCktc11gNRSUBsDCJ0QYShEVAMAA)

A couple of regexes, one to check if the input is `0/0`, and the other to replace the trailing `/0` with just `b` (and to remove the old `b`, `1`, and/or `-1`)

#### Explanation (old)

```perl6
{                          }  # Anonymous codeblock
 ~m/^0/     # Return 0 if the input starts with 0
       ||   # Otherwise
         S/             / /  # Substitute
                     \/0       # The /0
          (        )?          # Optionally starting with
           <wb>1               # 1 or -1
                |b             # Or b
                         b   # With just b
```

Comment: Won't this fail on input `0.5/0`? Although, I guess that kind of decimal isn't included in the spec

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

I ended up stealing [Erik's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/191110/53748) `ṾṖ$İƑ¡` for this one (otherwise I'd also have 19)...

```
ṖṖv0ḢṾṖ$İƑ¡,Ạ¡”boḢ
```

A full program which prints the result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzmlAVGbwcMeihzv3AZkqRzYcm3hooc7DXQsOLXzUMDcpHyj1//9/XWM9Q5MkfQMA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzmlAVGbwcMeihzv3AZkqRzYcm3hooc7DXQsOLXzUMDcpHyj1/@HuLYfbHzWtifz/30TfgMsQiA2A2AJE6FqARPRMgaSRnoExSAQkr2usZwhSmwTExiBCF0QYGsHlgFwA).

#### How?

```
ṖṖv0ḢṾṖ$İƑ¡,Ạ¡”boḢ - Main Link: list of characters S
Ṗ                  - discard right-most (of S)
 Ṗ                 - discard right-most
   0               - literal zero
  v                - evaluate as Jelly code with right argument (0)
                   - ... b is covert-to-base, so "nb0" gives [n]
    Ḣ              - head ([n]->n or n->n)
          ¡        - repeat...
         Ƒ         - ...# of times: is invariant under:
        İ          -   reciprocation (n->1/n)
       $           - ...action: last two links as a monad:
     Ṿ             -   un-evaluate (-1->"-1" or 1->"1")
      Ṗ            -   discard right-most ("-1"->"-" or "1"->"")
             ¡     - repeat...
            Ạ      - ...# of times: all?
           ,  ”b   - ...action: pair with a 'b' character
                o  - logical OR with:
                 Ḣ -   head (S)  (i.e. if we end with 0 use the 1st character of the input)
                   - implicit print
```

Comment: Ahhh, and I was thinking of ways I could abuse `v`... :D

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>28</s> 24 bytes

```
b?/0
b
^0b
0
(^|-)1b
$1b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYohDoBADAR93wHJIXq0d5DgkPziAk0QGARB8vfSFTNiZ5/zve5DvU/b7raOQkZNjIRS@3hQo07NfYqggQQLxAuWPIdLlooFnWtWfC2oEENa0H4)

First try at using Retina, so there's probably considerable room for golfing.

Comment: 18 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8F8jJslQ0z7JXt@AK4krziCJy@D/fxMgxxCIDYDYAkToWoBE9EyBpJGegTFIBCSva6xnCFKbBMTGIEIXRBgageQA "Retina – Try It Online")

Comment: After hunting for what `\b` does (I'm *that* inexperienced with regex), I was a bit disappointed to find that it can't be shortened to the unprintable backspace character. Anyhow, thanks

Comment: @UnrelatedString of course it can't be shortened to backspace, after all, `\b` is merely an ASCII representation of the backspace character in normal strings :P

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 19 bytes

```
ṖṖḟ”bȯ1VṾṖ$İƑ¡,Ạ¡”b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzmkgtGP@o4a5SSfWG4Y93LkPKKByZMOxiYcW6jzcteDQQpDU////dZP0DQA)

Full program.

Answer (score 3):

## [convey](http://xn--wxa.land/convey/), 47 bytes

```
['b'}
 >>~^]] '-'[
 91+>##"@]
{?~""@@<}
 ]11-^}
```

[Try it online!](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoiWydiJ31cbiA+Pn5eXV0gJy0nW1xuIDkxKz4jI1wiQF1cbns/flwiXCJAQDx9XG4gXTExLV59IiwidiI6MSwiaSI6Ii0xLzAifQ==)

I would like to put off the space betwen the number and 'b' in the output but i dont know how to do it :(

How it works (-3/0):

[image]

How it works (1/0):

[image]

Comment: Oh, the output was a bit jagged, you couldn't have done it properly. Fixed it in the interpreter, so it's now `3b` as one would expect it. :-)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>69</s> 66 bytes / <s>73</s> 70 bytes

Python already had a solution [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/191136/103772) but it didn't work properly on `-1/0`. That solution also uses regex while this one is vanilla python.

### Lambda version (66 bytes)

```python
lambda x:{"0":0,"1":"b","-1":"-b"}.get(a:=x[:-2].strip("b"),a+"b")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/RasMwDEXf9RXGL02Y7TnJBsGQ/kjXh3hzVsOWmtSFbGPfnklWywzWNbKkq5O@8uk8d31atml42T7GT/82itX9SCudVbKRTnqppKaH9vLXvIdcjW5YD063R3PJS0wVltRqfCDZ4pyu@SIGcZBPjxZbmxJtiT2L7vnHPBdtje04z7W6Mw33@hI7Fs3StFR1hLCm8JrZiFakyx5l4d6zg78ZlKS/T783/KdxrMepMJ0XEVUQcRbfiMY4is1qBwJPWuKcq6B2w36npirW9YbrAq4FyAcECYQIBRAYDwgObmiAKEBYQFBQkP4A)

### Print version (70 bytes)

```python
print({"0":0,"1":"b","-1":"-b"}.get(a:=input()[:-2].strip("b"),a+"b"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU/RagMhEHz3K2RfovQ0epeACPZHQh5yF9v64omxkBLy7dddA60wMzK7zq7lp32teXKlbst6jaECwFZqyk08wIA3A1jwMMMAii5qhqf@jE1cfEi5fDchT16NZ31rNRWBjXK4vJHIDaNYvJe4NB74CQ4UQjAIZ3qkI7b6SDJqM3Wz06Tt34N/2452hjNjH2vliafMX/mecTyvtdPAY76GHQ/vfCd7Id7jIuh7cjvsDbMIg3BEypGjj8i0ADlU7/NRZ8REpIhw/N78Ag)

### How it works :

starting from a string `x`:

- `x[:-2]` remove the `/0` part
- `.strip("b")` remove any eventual `b` present in the string
- `a:=` store our new string into `a`

Then we check if our new sring is equal to any `"0"`, `"1"` or `"-1"`:

- if True, `{...}.get()` will replace it by the appropriate string
- else, we will print it inchanged adding `"b"` at the end of the string

Thanks to ovs for reminding me that `str.strip` existed saving 3 bytes on each program

Comment: `.strip("b")` is 3 bytes shorter than `.split("b")[0]`.

Comment: @ovs my bad I totally forgot about that ^^'

Answer (score 2):

### [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 18B

All credit is to Jono 2906.

```
__:b=;[b]^:\1=[_]^
```

### Explanation

```
__                 # Take implicit input and remove the "trash" (/0).
  :b=              # Is the last character equal to b?
     ;             # Negate(decrement) this value.
      [b]          # If the last character is not b, append b.
         ^         # Reverse the stack.
          :\1=     # Is the first character equal to 1?
              [_]  # If so, reduce the value.
                 ^ # Reverse the stack back and implicit output.
```

[TIO!](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/Pt4qydY6Oik2zirG0DY6Pjbu/39dQyNDfQMA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 68 bytes

```python
import re
print(re.sub('^0b$','0',re.sub(r'(^1)?b?/0','b',input())))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolaugKDOvRKMoVa@4NElDPc4gSUVdR91AXQcqUqSuEWeoaZ9krw8UU09S18nMKygt0dAEgv//jZP0DQA)

Comment: Nice solution! But `import re` rises the bytecount to 64.

Comment: @movatica good point, new here so didn't realize import statement was included (although of course it is). Edited.

Comment: Welcome! :) You still can keep the shorter lambda version though! It does not need to be a full program. And the import statement can be placed after the lambda definition, so 64 bytes [are possible](https://tio.run/##LcgxCoAwDADA3Vc4CEmgaMVNED8iBYMVC1pLbEFfXx288cITt9N3eR2mvM8HL3N592LrKzGC0VyBAg3qHwE0LY08Nt8Bg7qJCneEU2IpNgdxPuKKzocUkYhyx41@AQ "Python 3 – Try It Online")!

Comment: @movatica ah, nice! I didn't find a way to make it work with import and lambda. Thank you

Comment: In the given exmple, `-1/0` should return `-b` and not `-1b`. You could achieve that bay changing `'(^1)?b?/0','b'` by `'(^(-)?1)?b?/0','\\2b'` at the cost of 7 bytes :/  Also you don't need the `$` in your first regex, neither you need the `r` in front of your string

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 45 bytes

```javascript
s=>+(n=s.split`/`[0])?[n*n-1?n:'-'[~n]]+'b':n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc7LCsIwEIXhvS8yiWXSpFEohdgHCYFebKUSJsUUl756XLiT2X6L/5zn@B7z/Nr2Ayndl7K6kt2tEuSyynvcjqEevA6y93QmND11gOA/FEIFE3RU5kQ5xUXF9BCrgEutQcrTnxpWNastz9jyZXVlvVHa8h3@C1pl@O8Tq5Zn5Nk0v9XyBQ)

#### Commented

```javascript
s =>                  // s = input: "numerator/0"
  +(                  //
    n = s.split`/`[0] // n = numerator, as a string
  ) ?                 // if n coerced to a Number is neither equal to 0 nor NaN:
    [ n * n - 1 ?     //   if abs(n) is not equal to 1:
        n             //     append the numerator
      :               //   else:
        '-'[~n]       //     append '-' if n = -1, or an empty string otherwise
    ] + 'b'           //   append 'b'
  :                   // else:
    n                 //   just output the numerator because it's either "0" or
                      //   an expression that already contains 'b'
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>298</s> <s>263</s> <s>217</s> 179 bytes

```c
i;f(char*s){for(i=0;s[i]-47&&(*s-49|s[1]-98||!printf("b"));)write(1,s+i,s[i++]!=98);}main(){char*s;gets(s);printf(*s-98&&*s-49|s[1]-47?*s-48?*s-45|s[1]-49?f(s),"b":"-b":"0":"b");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY1BCoMwEEXPoouQUUMjWEwaxIOICyvGDrS2ZIQu1LOnsXXRxXyYD@/9XvT3bhq9R2N5f@tcQrDYp@NYSUMNtqIoGeMJiUKv1OSt0Gpdo5fDabY8vsYABt4O54HnGaWYBSZN26jSCsz26HDisPy8Zhxm4gTmgINTK8b@1EVZ75/65vnodG0DlIWpSyz2kOHCrtm8z@VJfgA)

After a while, I actually managed to make this function the way you want. It's pretty big, I will say, I had to debug a lot.

Thanks to ceilingcat for golfing 35 bytes, another 46 bytes, and another 38 bytes.

Comment: Very well done! I'm proud of you!

Comment: @lyxal Thanks for the compliment. It took a long time to make this.

Comment: [171 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY1BCoMwFESvUrMI/zeGRrCYGMSDSBYqagOtlcTShXr2VEsXXQ3DMO@1vL3X4xBCe6vdyVfK6B4sLv3TgS2E9pU1PM0ohbPnqVp9lRiu5LpGk7Pj3ANpCKLGt7NzB0nsmY33D2MmKpREvT1qOwIuQzd78Kin1547SklK/4hpVh5NloQ3hH1d19@iKO0BMSeC5IdMbyEk4iI@ "C (clang) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 37 bytes

```
ToExpression[""<>#~Drop~-2]b/.b^_->b&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYqxDsIgFEX3fgYknQQK1aSDNk3U3aRuDRpoqCWxpQEGp/468oZzhnvuouJsFhXtqNJ0SU93/23ehGDdOiB0bvF@827biZCaUf16k1aX6eHtGgdM2qm7zsqrMRofOixL1vUxt0@/fW0cCnRkVcEzVaYBkQYWesoWtKphgU5qyuGrMzWIgLjIDR1QgWT6Aw)

Takes a list of characters as input.

Answer (score 1):

### C, <s>209</s> <s>203</s> 137 bytes

*-66 bytes thanks to ceilingcat*

```
char a[9];main(f){gets(a);f=strlen(a)-3;a[f+1]=0;printf((*a==55&a[1]==49&f==1?a[1]=98:*a==49&!f?*a=98:a[f]==98|*a==48&!f)?"%s":"%sb",a);}
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##HY3BCsIwEER/RQuWRK22tIWkYcmHhB7W0K0FDZLmpn57XHsZZubtsL6avc/Z3zHu0OnRPHEJguR7ntIqUBqCNcXHFNhXrUFHp2aE2rziEhIJcUSAvi/RcQudLgmgsVvSavhD7vZk2XHmNV9p9dmAYiBtcViLgeVWnPnbN@eqvTTdtf4B)

Comment: Putting in -0/0 gives -0b, but it was never in the example input or test cases, so it's correct.

Comment: [135 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYvBCsIwEER/RQuWRK22tIWkYcmHhB7W0K0FDZL0pn57XHsZZubN@Gr2Pmd/x7hDp0fzxCUIkm@CtMbHFMQ8rUmglFVr0NGpGaE2r7iElYQ4IkDfl@i4hU6XBNDYLWk1/CF3e7LsOPObV1p9NqAYSFscUjGw3IozSvPNuWovTXetfw)

Answer (score 1):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), 64 bytes

```
6a8m1s2x1v2m4a2x2v1x1f1r3x1v2e3x2v3e1o1f0x1x2f2m4a1o0x1x3f1o0x1f
```

**Explanation** (with `0x` commands removed)

```
6a8m1s2x1v             # Set variable 1 equal to 47 ("/")
2m4a2x2v               # Set variable 2 equal to 98 ("b")
1x1f                   # Function 1
    1r                 # Read a byte of input
      3x1v2e           # Jump to function 2 if it equals variable 1
            3x2v3e     # Jump to function 3 if it equals variable 2
                  1o1f # Otherwise, output it and jump back to the start of the function
1x2f2m4a1o             # Function 2
                       # Set the register equal to 98 and output once
1x3f1o                 # Function 3
                       # Output once
1f                     # Call function 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-p`, 37 bytes

```ruby
sub /(^1|-\K1)?b?\/0/,?b
sub /^0b/,?0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v7g0SUFfI86wRjfG21DTPsk@Rt9AX8c@iQssEWeQBOQY/P9vom/AZQjEBkBsASJ0LUAieqZA0kjPwBgkApLXNdYDUUlAbAwidEGEoRFYK0jxv/yCksz8vOL/ugUA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 96 bytes

```cpp
#import<ios>
int f(int r,int i){i-=~r;i||printf("-");i--*~-i&&printf("%d",i?:r);i&&printf("b");}
```

Takes as input an integer `r` denoting a real number and the coefficient of a multiple of \$b\$ `i`.

Then "divides" by zero and does some hacking to avoid printing deviating results.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/BrsIgEEX3fAWpUUEhturCWKsfUrtQfH3OwkIQXYj46xVo1VncOzl3MpkRSvF/Idp2ABcltdmAvG4RNAbXJKhmQYFa4MVL5/B8Ku1JTRKe0Bw4n7w4jEYfODwlDHZr7aMfPPpJ14Y9lwM05C7hRJFF2FeARpRVOa9wEYlFdukYslmQNMgqKl9F7TDrbdFZR7N5sLDD5Sh6LXV8AnCB09zbBl/h8SdrYgSdfdsyrahPp1PaX4D7iiFUPme46zI/@Y3VzYjzQZPxvhn32CHXvgE)

Comment: [87 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZZDBasMwDIbvfgrNZSVebZZ0O5S5Ya@QexbC6sRFsDnBTXeYcV89s53Qy3T4fvH/QgipcRRnpeZ50/UaTQ@VwO22bU9X/JrQtKNFM@mMBILOIi2PROZQlDcrHyoqKJMoxNOtoo8d5fj@Zpms6CnYfo7D359osp8BO0YcgVDRnFTd1PsGyuQ44l49J66IyCMOieKQuNh8lZdFFrfYR4k7vCRJ9WDTpQgl5DLIES742w86mxR7vrd13rCQ7nZsvQDWSiE2IeewdEWYvMf/nkM/DF1zT/z8Bw "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 71 bytes

```c
f(r,i){i-=~r;i||printf("-");i--*~-i&&printf("%d",i?:r);i&&printf("b");}
```

Same as my C++ solution but with less boilerplate.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BDoIwEETv/YqGRGm1jYAeiEj8EOSA1eoeBFPRg7X8OrYFcQ8zkzebbQW/CNH3kigGVAPPO5XB53NXULeSBDygGXC@6DjM5z84OwUM9ltlqz882k3T24xvFdTk1cCJIo2wHQdbUZRFUuLcE430xjCkYyeRk9QrT70OmI22HmygceLM3TAZ8i4bRdwLgHMcZdZ2@AHvcyNJK@hqikVUUtsul3T8AR7Hl1DanuEhxXZzqu/PVlwrRcJDHY7YINN/AQ)

Comment: @ceilingcat Thanks.

Comment: [65 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY7BcsIgEIbvPMWWTg0oTBP14JRm@gq5pzkoCboHE4fGHsrgq6dAMu7h/3e@fxdWy7PW0/Tadgb7DiqJq9XNYj8aRgyzArlDWT6seqmopFyhlOtHRd9aKvDrw3JV0VPAfgorcD1iz34HbDlxBEJFOOq6qbcNlIk44vZeEFdEyaMckspD0hmLxXazzbTYRotveEWSm8Gy@ANCCbkK9gk/@NcNho2avz/bOm94SDcbvlwAS6UQm5ALmLsiTD7j233Ul6Nl2XefLdgTP/0D "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
¨¨ÐĀiáм'b«Dþi1K
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9vc2FiaWX//8KowqjDkMSAacOh0LwnYsKrRMO@aTFL//8tMS8w) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/QysOrTg84UhD5uGFF/aoJx1a7XJ4X6ah9//aWp3/0Uom@gZKOkqGYNIATFpAKF0LiIyeKZg20jMwhohD1Ooa6xlC9CaBSWMIpQuhDI1AqmIB).

**Explanation:**

```python
¨¨               # Remove the last two characters of the (implicit) input
  Ð              # Then triplicate the string
   Āi            # Pop one, and if it's NOT 0 (using Python-style truthify):
     á           #  Pop again and only leave the letters (in case it contains a "b")
      м          #  And remove those letters
       'b«      '#  Then append a trailing "b"
          D      #  Duplicate it
           þ     #  Pop and only leave the digits
            i    #  If this is exactly 1:
             1K  #   Remove the 1
                 # (after which the top of the stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Brainfuck, 25 bytes

```
>,[>,]<[-<+>]<+++[<]>[.>]
```

### Explanation

```
>,[>,]        read from stdin
<[-<+>]<+++   add last two cells and add three ( ascii('/') + ascii('0') + 3 = ascii('b')
[<]>          move pointer to first char to output
[.>]          output until cell w/ value 0
```

Comment: ```b/0``` expected ```b```, got ```bb```; ```0/0``` expected ```0```, got ```0b```; ```-1/0``` expected ```-b```, got ```-1b```.

Comment: Yeah, basically this only substitutes the `/0` for `b` and doesn't take into account any of the cases for `0b`, `1b`, `-1b` or any inputs that already contain a `b`

Answer (score 0):

## Symja, 85 bytes

```
d(x_):=If((e=StringReplace(x,"/0"->""))!="0",If(StringContainsQ(e,"b"),e,e<>"b"),"0")
```

[Try it Online!](https://symjaweb.appspot.com/input?i=d%28x%5f%29%3a%3dIf%28%28e%3dStringReplace%28x%2c%22%2f0%22%2d%3e%22%22%29%29%21%3d%220%22%2cIf%28StringContainsQ%28e%2c%22b%22%29%2ce%2ce%3c%3e%22b%22%29%2c%220%22%29%3bd%28%223b%2f0%22%29)

I finally answered my own question!